# How do I add an array ref to the middle of an existing array in Perl?

Tags: arrays, perl, multidimensional-array

I want to be able to place an array into an array. For example, I may have an array like this:

```
my @array1 = ("element 1","element 2","element 3");
```

Then I have another array

```
my $array_ref = ["this will", "go between", "element 1 and 2"];
```

I want to place `$array_ref` into the first so that the first array
looks like this:

```
("element 1",["this will", "go between", "element 1 and 2"],"element 2","element 3")
```

I can't seem to do this. I looked all over Google and found nothing.

Comment: The second one is not an array. It is an array reference.

Comment: Check `perldoc perlreftut` for an excellent, brief tutorial on references in Perl.

Answer (score 7):

So you use [splice](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/splice.html) to replace 0 elements beginning with element 1 (the second element, the first is element 0) with your desired elements:

```
splice( @array, 1, 0, ["this will", "go between", "element 1 and 2"] );
```

Or possibly you mean:

```
splice( @array, 1, 0, "this will", "go between", "element 1 and 2" );
```

if you don't want nested arrays.

Comment: I think he meant insert into an existing array too. Not totally clear though.

Answer (score 5):

The important point to remember is the distinction between () and []. '()' gives you a list of elements, for eg. (1, 2, 3) which you could then assign to an array variable as so -

```
my @listOfElem = (1, 2, 3);
```

'[]' is an [array reference](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html#Making-References) and returns a scalar value which you could incorporate into your list.

```
my $refToElem = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
```

In your case, if you are initializing the first array then you could simply insert the second array elements like so,

```
my @listOfElem = (1, 2, ['a', 'b', 'c'], 3);
#This gives you a list of "4" elements with the third
#one being an array reference

my @listOfElem = (1, 2, $refToELem, 3);
#Same as above, here we insert a reference scalar variable

my @secondListOfElem = ('a', 'b', 'c');
my @listOfElem       = (1, 2, \@secondListOfElem, 3);
#Same as above, instead of using a scalar, we insert a reference
#to an existing array which, presumably, is what you want to do.

#To access the array within the array you would write -
$listOfElem[2]->[0]  #Returns 'a'
@{listOfElem[2]}[0]  #Same as above.
```

If you have to add the array elements on the fly in the middle of the array then just use 'splice' as detailed in the other posts.

Answer (score 3):

This is the sort of thing you'll understand after going through the first part of [Intermediate Perl](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596102067/), which covers references and data structures. You can also look in the [Perl data structures cookbook](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html).

In short, you store an array in another array by using a reference (which is just a  scalar):

```
my @big_array = ( $foo, $bar, \@other_array, $baz );
```

In your case, you used the anonymous array constructor and just want to splice it into an existing array. There's nothing special about it being an array reference:

```
splice @big_array, $offset, $length, @new_items;
```

In your case, you wanted to start at element 1, remove 0 items, and add your reference:

```
splice @big_array, 1, 0, $array_ref;
```

Answer (score 2):

What you have is an array and an array reference.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @array    = ("element 1","element 2","element 3");
my $arrayref = ["this will", "go between", "element 1 and 2"];

splice( @array, 1, 0, $arrayref );  # Grow the array with the list (which is $arrayref)

for ( my $i = 0; $i <= $#array; $i++ ) {
    print "\@array[$i] = $array[$i]\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [splice](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/splice.html).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
my @array1 = ("element 1", "element 2", "element 3");
my $array_ref = ["this will", "go between", "element 1 and 2"];
splice(@array1, 1, 0, $array_ref);
print Dumper \@array1;
```

This will print the following:

```
$VAR1 = [
          'element 1',
          [
            'this will',
            'go between',
            'element 1 and 2'
          ],
          'element 2',
          'element 3'
        ];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try having a temporary array, like this:

```
@temp_arr = ("this will", "go between", "element 1 and 3");
@my_arr = ("element 1", \@temp_arr, "element 3");
```

You can use the sub-elements like this:

```
print $my_arr[1]->[0]; # prints 'this will'
```

Refer to the subarray like this:

```
print @$my_arr[1]; # Right! Prints 'this willgo betweenelement 1 and 2'

# Don't do this:
print $my_arr[1]; # Wrong! Prints something like: 'ARRAY(0xDEADBEEF)'
```