# How to store variable-arrays inside another array?

Tags: perl

I have a perl-query on saving arrays inside another array. A related query was asked before([How do I add an array ref to the middle of an existing array in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025342/)), but I could not find answer to mine, so I am posting it here.

I have 10 text files, each having approximately 100 lines of text. I want to pick all those lines containing the word "important". Script for doing this operation is below. I save all lines containing word "important" in an array. So, from each text file, I get an array. I want to save all those arrays inside another array ?

```
my @list_of_files = ("input1.txt", "input2.txt","input3.txt"); my $list_of_files = @list_of_files;

for ($file=0, $file<$list_of_files; $files++){
 open INPUT_FILE, "$list_of_files[$file]" or die "can't open $file : $!";
 my @input = <INPUT_FILE>;
 my $size = @input;

 for ($num=0; $num<$size; $num++){
  if ($input[$num] =~ m/important/) {
   push (@sub_array, $output);
  }
 }
 close INPUT_FILE;
 push (@main_array, \@sub_array);   
}
```

elements of @sub_array changes every time, so, how do I preserve elements of all sub_arrays ? I would like to have final output as @main_array, which contains 3 elements, each element is an array of elements (lines containing the word "important")

Any help is much appreciated TIA

Comment: Always add `use strict;` and `use warnings;` to the beginning of you Perl files.

Answer (score 5):

I would do it slightly differently to bvr. But his points still stand.

```
# use qw() to define line with less punctuation
my @list_of_files = qw(input1.txt input2.txt input3.txt);

my @lines_in_file;

foreach my $file (@list_of_files) {
  open(my $in, '<', $file) or die "can't open $file : $!";

  # declare an array, not a scalar
  my @lines;

  # idiomatic use of while(<>) puts each record into $_
  while (<$in>) {
    # /../ works on $_ by default.
    # Postfix condition is more readable
    push @lines, $_ if /important/;
  }

  # Take reference to array and push it onto main array
  push @lines_in_file, \@lines;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I would solve your problem like this:

```
my @list_of_files = ("input1.txt", "input2.txt", "input3.txt");

my @lines_in_file = ();                 # target array
for my $file (@list_of_files) {
    open(my $in,'<',$file) or die "can't open $file : $!";

    my $lines = [];                     # scalar containing arrayref for important lines
    while(my $input = <$in>) {
        if($input =~ /important/) {
            push @$lines, $input;       # push into arrayref
        }
    }
    close $in;

    push @lines_in_file, $lines;        # push arrayref into main array
}
```

Few things to note:

- perl for can traverse array without hassle of C-style for
- it is better to process file line-by-line, instead of reading whole thing into memory, especially for line based processing
- `[]` construct new arrayref in each iteration. If you reuse `@sub_array` in each loop and take reference of it, you end up with many references to same thing

Comment: I prefer `use autodie;` to `open ... or die ...` particularly on StackOverflow answers.

Comment: Also `while( my $input = <$in> ){ ... }` automatically gets transformed into `while( defined( my $input = <$in> ) ){ ... }`

Comment: @Brad Gilbert - I changed the `while` loop per your suggestion, I did not know about this feature. I know and use `autodie`, but it adds one more concept to gather and it is difficult to understand from  `open` call if you don't know about it.

Answer (score 3):

If you are going to write something in Perl now and then, you will have to understand how references work and how to build complex data structures.

Being a Perl newbie myself, I would recommend you to visit [perldoc.perl.org](http://perldoc.perl.org), the [manuals section](http://perldoc.perl.org/index-overview.html), and work through first three lessons. It would only take you about an hour and a half and you will have an idea on how to solve your problem and others of that kind.

The [tutorials](http://perldoc.perl.org/index-tutorials.html) are really helpful - brief and practical. You will learn to pass data structures around and iterate on them and whatnot.

For testing, consider using [Data::Dumper](http://perldoc.perl.org/Data/Dumper.html) and `print Dumper($var)` to look inside your complicated data structures easily.

Comment: @Brad, thanks for editing, I'll try to provide links myself next time, but it's tedious when writing from an android device. %)